# react-validation: Validate if checkbox is checked

Tags: reactjs, validation

I have the following code where I want to validate if a text-input has a value and a checkbox is checked. The validation of the text-input is working but I don't know how to validate the checkbox.
Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-dew-1fk61?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark